# Windows server 2008 R2 drivers problem

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-server-2008

I have installed Windows server 2008 R2.  I have a Lenovo G560 notebook.  Unable to find drivers online... can anyone help?

I want to install Microsoft SharePoint and so I installed this system.
I have Windows 7 installed already.

Comment: You're installing a server OS on a laptop? Why?

Comment: @josh, I was thinking that exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to find drivers specifically designed for a server OS for a laptop, but if you get a list of your devices you might be able to find most of them individually. I am guessing that the video driver might be an issue and possibly any chipset drivers you are looking for.

Comment: I am unable to find network drivers. Can't connect with my wireless network.

Comment: You can use the unknown device identifier to get details about the network adapter (http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html). What you need is the chipset. You can then search for that chipset with server 2008. There isn't going to be an easy way to find what you're looking for as most servers do not use wireless cards, so you're not likely to find much.